# How to bring "System.Drawing.Image" to DIB

Tags: vb.net, vb6, dib

I have created a consumable COM Class Library.

The class library gets the image of a camera. It's of type Image / Bitmap.

I consume the class library in VB6, and I need to show this image in VB6.

How could I convert this System.Drawing.Image to something that VB6 can display?

Can I use a DIB (using CreateDIBSection, etc.)?

If yes, how exactely can a System.Drawing.Image be converted to a DIB?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what I've done in the past. First, a couple prerequisites:

- you get a Byte() from the COM Class Library
- you set a reference to **Microsoft Windows Image Aquisition Library**

With these in place, the code is pretty simple.  `Camera` is a COM Class Library where the `Retrieve` method returns a Byte() that gets loaded into an Image control:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdLoad_Click()
   Dim cam As Camera.Image
   Set cam = New Camera.Image
   Image1.Picture = LoadPictureFromByteArray(cam.Retrieve())
End Sub

Private Function LoadPictureFromByteArray(Image() As Byte) As StdPicture
   Dim vec As WIA.Vector
   Set vec = New WIA.Vector
   vec.BinaryData = Image
   Set LoadPictureFromByteArray = vec.ImageFile.FileData.Picture
End Function
```