# Display picture as LONG BLOB from SQL Server into Image Control using ADODB Stream

Tags: excel, vba

I got problem when display Picture from SQL Long BLOB to image Picture Control.

this code :

```
Private Sub LoadPict()
Dim SQLKoneksi As String: SQLKoneksi = "DRIVER=MySQL ODBC 5.1 DRIVER; SERVER=127.0.0.1; DATABASE=db_spp; UID=root; PWD=;"
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection: Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.Open SQLKoneksi

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset: Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim stm As ADODB.Stream: Set stm = New ADODB.Stream

Dim SQLQuery As String: SQLQuery = "SELECT foto_petugas FROM petugas WHERE id_petugas='PTG001'"
rs.Open SQLQuery, conn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

stm.Type = adTypeBinary
stm.Open
stm.Write rs("foto_petugas").Value
stm.Position = 0
Me.Gambar.Picture = stm.Read
stm.Close: rs.Close: conn.Close
Set stm = Nothing: Set rs = Nothing: Set conn = Nothing
End sub
```

I get message error is "Object Required" in this line :

```
Me.Gambar.Picture = stm.Read
```

How to Solve it? thanks

Comment: I recently answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61371812/5162073) showing how to load a picture from a byte array.

Comment: Oke thank you, Solve it